# Kohana - Run code on every page load (every controller)

Tags: kohana

Where I have to put my code if I want load (run) this code everytime when site load (in every controller)?

Thanks!
Martin.

Answer (score 2):

First, build main controllers, the others extend them. Two methods are very usefull: before() and after(). By overriding and chaining them (super::), you will able to do it.

[Api Controller](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Controller_Template)

Comment: But, I have do (on example) this code:

`$_SESSION['lastvisit'] = time(); echo 'test';`

on every page (controller) in my project. 

On example:

controller Welcome

`public function action_index()
echo 'do test';`

will output `testdo test`

Comment: Base controllers could be abstract too. You could load a public user object, play with session parmeters or prepare your layout if you make it extends Controller_Template

Answer (score 1):

As nopnop77 says, you could create base controller which extends Kohana's default controller, and then extend this base controller in your application. For example:

Create a Base Controller file `application/classes/Controller/Base.php`:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No Direct Script Access');

class Controller_Base extends Kohana_Controller
{

    protected $session = NULL;

    public function before()
    {
        parent::before();

        // start the session
        $this->session = Session::instance();
    }
}
```

Then any classes which extend the base class have access to the the variable/methods in the base class. For example: Login Controller e.g. `application/classes/Controller/Login.php` which extends the Base class:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No Direct Script Access');

class Controller_Login extends Controller_Base
{

    public function action_index()
    {
        // you can access the session variable here
        echo $this->session;
    }
}
```